# How to upload Multiple files with multiple inputs Using CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter

plaese help me dear,
I have a form where i want to upload files with multiple inputs(employee_name,resume,offer_letter,joining_letter) 
     using codeigniter.
    My form looks like:

```
     <form class="form-horizontal form-bordered" action="<?php echo base_url('save_employee/');?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">

        <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Employee Image</label>
                <input type="file" class="form-control" name="employee_name">
              </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Resume/CV</label>
                <input type="file" class="form-control" name="resume">
              </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Offer letter</label>
                <input type="file" class="form-control" name="offer_letter">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Joining Letter</label>
                <input type="file" class="form-control" name="joining_letter">
            </div>
        </form
```

Comment: What's your issue? What are your error messages? Did you try codeigniter upload library? Update your question with some code that you've tried.

Comment: make file field name array and set field attribute `multiple="multiple"`;

Comment: You Want fields Like This Or Like 1 Field To uplod Multiple Uploads

Answer (score 0):

Put This In Your Controller Here Taking Four fields To Upload The Files

```
public function Add() {
        $data                          =        array();
        $config                        =        array(
        'upload_path' => 'upload',
        'allowed_types' => 'gif|jpg|png',
        'max_size' => 250,
        'max_width' => 1920,
        'max_heigh' => 1080,
    );
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if($this->input->post('Submit'))    {
        $file_data                  =       $this->upload->data();
        $data['cnic_img']           =       $file_data['file_name'];

        $file_data                  =       $this->upload->data();
        $data['domcie_img']         =       $file_data['file_name'];

        $file_data                  =       $this->upload->data();
        $data['profile_img']        =       $file_data['file_name'];

        $file_data                  =       $this->upload->data();
        $data['report_img']         =       $file_data['file_name'];
         $lat_id                    =       $this->your_model->save($data);
        }
        $this->load->View('your_template');
     }
```

Put This In You Model

```
function save($data){
    $this->db->insert('your_table', $data);
    return $this->db->insert_id();
   }
```

Here Is Your View

```
<div class="portlet-body form">
<!-- BEGIN FORM-->
<?php echo $this->upload->display_errors(''); ?>
<form class="form-horizontal" action="" <?php echo form_open_multipart();?>
<div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="CNIC Image" class="col-md-3 control-label">CNIC Image:</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-9">
                                        <input type="file" id="cnic_img" name="cnic_img">
                                        <p class="help-block">
                                             Upload CNIC image Here.
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="portlet-body form">
                            <div class="form-body">

                                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="Domicile Image" class="col-md-3 control-label">Domicile Image:</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-9">
                                        <input type="file" id="domcie_img" name="domcie_img">
                                        <p class="help-block">
                                                Upload Domicile Image Here.
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="portlet-body form">
                            <div class="form-body">

                                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="Domicile Image" class="col-md-3 control-label">Profile Image:</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-9">
                                        <input type="file" id="profile_img" name="profile_img" >
                                        <p class="help-block">
                                                 Upload Profile Image Here.
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="portlet-body form">
                            <div class="form-body">

                                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="Domicile Image" class="col-md-3 control-label">Police validation Report:</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-9">
                                        <input type="file" id="report_img" name="report_img">
                                        <p class="help-block">
                                                 Upload Police Validation Report Here.
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> **This example is helped for some peoples.**

```
    $file = $_FILES;
    
    $config['upload_path'] = './images/product/'; 
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg'; 
    $config['max_size'] = 2000;
    $config['max_width'] = 1500;
    $config['max_height'] = 1500;
    $config['encrypt_name'] = TRUE;
        
    if (empty($file['product_image']['name'])) {
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('product_image', 'Product image', 'required');            
} else {
    // Load and initialize upload library 
    $this->load->library('upload', $config); 
    $this->upload->initialize($config);
    
    if($this->upload->do_upload('product_image')){ 
        $fileData = $this->upload->data(); 
    } else { 
        $web['error']['product_image'] = $this->upload->display_errors();
        $this->load->view('web_template',$web); 
    } 
}

if (empty($file['customer_image']['name'])) {
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('customer_image', 'Customer image', 'required');            
} else {        
    // Load and initialize upload library 
    $this->load->library('upload', $config); 
    $this->upload->initialize($config);
    
    if($this->upload->do_upload('customer_image')){ 
        $cusfileData = $this->upload->data(); 
    } else { 
        $web['error']['customer_image'] = $this->upload->display_errors();
        $this->load->view('web_template',$web); 
    }
}
```

> **Get the image file name to insert data**

```
$data = array(
    'product_image' => $fileData['file_name'],
    'customer_image' => $cusfileData['file_name']
);
```